# Is this a correct definition of the Cartesian Product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is from Analytical Topology by Burgess:

> The notion of a function is thus involved in the construction of the so-called **Cartesian product** of a given family of subsets $\{X_i\}, i\in I$, of elements of S such that $x_i\in X_i$ for each in I; that is, the Cartesian Product, denoted by $\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_i$, is determined by the set of all functions $f$ from $I$ into $S$ such that $f(i)\in X_i$ for each $i$ in $I$.

Compared to the [Wiki definition of the Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), I can't make head or tail of the above. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained further down in the Wikipedia page. It's a way to generalize the notion of "n-tuple of objects". If you think about it, to pick an element $(x_1, \ldots,x_n)$ in $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$ is the same thing as to pick a specific map $f:\{1,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow \bigcup X_i$ such that $f(i)$ is in $X_i$. The correspondence is given by

$$ (x_i) \leftrightarrow f \text{ defined by } f(i) = x_i.$$

This generalizes in the obvious way to any set of indices.